# How to use getent passwd command to see if the user exists and belongs to a particular group

Tags: linux, shell, sh

I want to check if a user exists in a particular group.

```
getent passwd user_name &> /dev/null
```

The above command checks if the user is there. But I want to also see if it belongs to a group named for example support

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should run

```
groups username
```

to list the groups the user belongs.

If the user does not exist, the output is

```
    groups: username: No such user
```

So the bash script can be

```
output=$(groups username)
if [[ $output == *"groupname"* ]]; then
    echo yes
fi
```

Comment: i need to check if user testuser exists and belongs to group testsupport. This code only shows if the user exists or shows the lists of groups the user belong

Comment: @Anza The second half of code indeed check if user belongs to a group or not.

Comment: @Anza First, your "one line" command does not contain "checking", it only print a line containing group-id (and importantly, only the id of the primary group, ignoring other groups). If you are talking about one command, `groups username` provides more informations than `getnet...`